# iOS Swift call Crashes because of Invalid mobile number

Tags: ios, swift, phone-number, phone-call

This is the code I am using to make call. But it crashes because of invalid number.
the number with 11 digits starts with 6 crashes
but the number with 11 digits starts with 0 works fine
normally with 10 digits works fine.
Can anyone help?

```
let myurl=URL(string: "tel://\(selectedEmployeeContact)")
    let isInstalled=UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(myurl!)
    if(isInstalled)
    {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(myurl!)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(myurl!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the current answers aren't addressing your issue; my question is: what line is the app crashing on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code to prevent the crash:-

```
guard let myurl=URL(string: "tel://\(selectedEmployeeContact)") else {return}
let isInstalled=UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(myurl)
```

> If your myurl is nil then it will crash because it will force
>   unwrapped the Value.

Answer (score 1):

Question: What does the expression myurl! do if myurl is nil?

Answer: The exclamation mark will make it crash. Intentionally.

So start your debugger. Set a breakpoint, then step through each line. Check the relevant variables. Most likely you will find that myurl is nil. If not, step through the code line by line and tell us exactly where the crash happens.